# Syntax error on token "return", byte expected

Tags: java

I am designing a code for a project at school and the only error code I get when compiling the following code is  Syntax error on token "return", byte expected.

```
static public int getMonthlyTotal(){
  //Calulates utilities
  int monthlyTotal = 0;
  //Define imput streams
  InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);  

    monthlyTotal = (150 + 60 + 20 + 60 + 800);
}
return monthlyTotal;
```

Comment: stare at `return monthlyTotal;` (and one line before too)

Comment: Swap the last two lines, ie. move the `return` before the closing `}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
static public int getMonthlyTotal(){
  //Calulates utilities
  int monthlyTotal = 0;
  //Define imput streams
  InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);  

    monthlyTotal = (150 + 60 + 20 + 60 + 800);
    return monthlyTotal;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are giving the return statement out of the scope of method
give like this it will work

```
static public int getMonthlyTotal() {
        // Calulates utilities
        int monthlyTotal = 0;
        // Define imput streams
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

        monthlyTotal = (150 + 60 + 20 + 60 + 800);
        return monthlyTotal;

    }
```